# jQuery not loading in MAMP (1.11.2) when running website locally

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Firstly I apologise for the fact that this question has been asked many times before, however none of the answers solved my problem so I thought that I would ask the question here.

I downloaded jQuery 1.11.2 (uncompressed) to locally develop my website however my code which worked using the jQuery built in to jsfiddle did not work locally. Therefore I added the following code to check if the jQuery had loaded:

```
<script src="file:///Applications/MAMP/htdocs/phpv1/v1/jquery-1.11.2.js">
if (typeof jQuery != 'undefined') {

alert("jQuery library is loaded!");

}else{

alert("jQuery library is not found!");

}
</script>
```

However I didn't get either alert box making me wonder if it was the Javascript which was not working, however I got Javascript to work using some simple form validation code. I am using MAMP to host the PHP and Google Chrome as the broswer. The file is saved as a HTML file and the code is as follows:

```
<html>    
<style>
 #test{
max-height: 150px;
max-width: 200px;
overflow: auto;
background: #50a8ff;    
 }
</style>    
<head>
<script src="file:///Applications/MAMP/htdocs/phpv1/v1/jquery-1.11.2.js">
if (typeof jQuery != 'undefined') {

alert("jQuery library is loaded!");

}else{

alert("jQuery library is not found!");

}
</script>    
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

I obviously can't use the Google hosted library as I am running the website locally. To determine the file path for the Javascript I opened it in Google Chrome.

Comment: can't you just put it in your web root, and use a relative path from there? Just as you would if you stored it locally on the real site?

Comment: You can actually use the google hosted library. Just make sure you put the "http://" before it.

Comment: `<script src="file:///Applications/MAMP/htdocs/phpv1/v1/jquery-1.11.2.js">` there are three `///` try adding two`2`

Comment: why are you using `file://` protocol? Just use a relative path. Also you can use CDN resources  so long as you have internet connection

Comment: Are you seeing any error in your Javascript console?

Comment: Thanks everyone for their help, I obviously had made several fundamental errors!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't put content inside a `<script>` tag that has a `src` attribute. Use two separate tags to test it:

```
<script src="file:///Applications/MAMP/htdocs/phpv1/v1/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
<script>
if (typeof jQuery != 'undefined') {
    alert("jQuery library is loaded!");
}else{
    alert("jQuery library is not found!");
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options here: either you use the jQuery hosted by Google

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

or then you would need to change to use relative path to file with something like this

```
<script src="jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
```

when the *jquery-1.11.2.js* is on the same folder as your HTML page.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running this from MAMP you need to change this line -

```
<script src="file:///Applications/MAMP/htdocs/phpv1/v1/jquery-1.11.2.js">
```

to this -

```
<script src="phpv1/v1/jquery-1.11.2.js" type="text/javascript">
```

if your HTML files are in 'htdocs'. I included `type="text/javascript"` in the event you're not using HTML5.